# Calculus and trigonometry course

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics, calculus

Can anyone please tell me any book or refer any kind of short term course on calculus and trigonometry required for physics.

Answer (score 0):

For calculus I would recommend "Calculus", from Howard Anton. For me an absolute gem to start understanding the calculus you need for physics. Is the book which finally helped me grasp all the stuff related to double and triple integrals, cylindrical an  spherical coordinates, etc...